# Finding a remainder using division of 10

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to find the right most bit of any integer. So, i can find the remainder of the value divided by 10 (i.e) a = rem(Num1,10); in Matlab.. How to do the same using Verilog . I have Xilinx 14.1 and 9.1..

Comment: Can you explain what did you do so far?

Comment: For a packed array variable like `reg [7:0] a`, the LSB, the rightmost bit can be sliced simply as `a[0]`. Please be clear about the intent.

Comment: Like in your other question, I wouldn't talk about bits, here, but digits. You want the least significant digit.

Comment: I used matlab code for rounding off  a = rem(Num1,10); on finding the right most digit is "< 5" or "=or >5 " i rounded off the number ... say 54 has 4,that is less than 5 so i subtracted it from 54 to get 50.... say 57 has 7, that is greater than 5 so i added 3 to get 60. i am trying to do this in verilog.... if there any direct function well and good if not how shall i proceed..

Answer (score 0):

% is the modulus operator in verilog, just like in C

looking at the comments, it looks like you want to make a rounding function: here's something that will do that:

One note: the code below will be VERY inefficient since % is expensive in hardware.  Consider dividing by a power of 2 like 8 or 16 instead of 10.

```
module round
(
    input   wire[31:0] x,
    output  reg[31:0] rounded
);

    reg[31:0]   remainder;

    always @(*) begin

        // % operator is VERY slow and expensive!!!
        remainder = (x % 32'd10);

        // the lines below are decently efficient
        if (remainder < 32'd5)
            rounded = x - remainder;
        else
            rounded = x + (32'd10 - remainder);

    end


endmodule
```

Comment: Sir it says an error "Operator % is only supported when the second operand is a power of 2."